# Login with a button-click in a mail

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to login with a click on a button in a mail, sent by laravel `Mail::send()`?

So I send a mail to the user with `Mail::send()`. I want the user to open the mail, click the button in it and that he will be automatically logged in so he sees his profile page immediately.

How would you guys suggest I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is the exact same answer I gave in another similar question.

Create a table to store `login codes`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('login', function($table) {
        $table->string('id')->primary();

        $table->string('user_id');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Every time you generate a link you add a line to this table:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$login = Login::create(['id' => Login::generateID(), 'user_id' => $user->id]);

$url = URL::route('loginByEmail', $login->id);

Mail::send(...)
```

Create the route for your login link:

```
Route::get('loginByEmail/{code}', 
            array('as' => 'loginByEmail', 'uses' =>'LogonController@loginByEmail')
          );
```

Then when your user clicks the link you can automatically log him in, immediatelly invalidate that link and redirect him to profile, here's the controller method:

```
public function loginByEmail()
{
    $login = Login::findOrFail(Input::get('login_id'));

    $user = User::find($login->user_id);

    Auth::login($user);

    $login->delete();

    return Redirect::route('profile');
}
```

And create an Artisan Command to periodiacally delete old records on that table:

```
Login::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(2))->delete();
```

As another security mesure, you should also check if that login code is not too old.

This can be the code for `generateID()`, it's a basic UUID code generation:

```
public static function v4() 
{
   return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        // 32 bits for "time_low"
        random_mcrypt(), random_mcrypt(),

        // 16 bits for "time_mid"
        random_mcrypt(),

        // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
        // four most significant bits holds version number 4
        random_mcrypt(0x0fff) | 0x4000,

        // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
        // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
        // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
        random_mcrypt(0x3fff) | 0x8000,

        // 48 bits for "node"
        random_mcrypt(), random_mcrypt(), random_mcrypt()
    );
}
```

No strings attached to anything on your system.